# Kubernetes automatically apply manifests on cluster start

Tags: kubernetes

Beginner question regarding kubernetes:

In our tiny scale usage scenario we are running minikube as a single node cluster. While I know how I can autostart minikube using systemd, I am wondering what is the correct way to automatically restore deployments on minikube startup.

I.e. can I cause `kubectl apply -f myApplication.yaml` to happen automatically when minikube starts? (I would prefer a kubernetes solution if that exists, if there is only a minikube specific way I will take it).

(I know that I could just create a startup script that starts minikube and runs the apply command, but I was hoping that there is something like a magic folder from which all manifest files are applied, or an `kubectl apply --persistent` flag or something of the sorts)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like K3S is able to do this, but I was hoping for a generic kubernetes solution and not a runtime specific one:

https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/advanced/#auto-deploying-manifests

> Auto-Deploying Manifests Any file found in
> /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/manifests will automatically be deployed
> to Kubernetes in a manner similar to kubectl apply, both on startup
> and when the file is changed on disk. Deleting files out of this
> directory will not delete the corresponding resources from the
> cluster.